# how to make use of old system libraries

Tags: gcc, curl, linker, shared-libraries, libssl

We have a project and shared libraries libprivate.so (private so) which was using old libraries libcurl.so.3. The system was upgraded with new system libraries libcurl.so.4.

For some internal issues, right now we do not want to make use of latest libraries libcurl.so.4, we want to make use of libcurl.so.3.

Hence I copied libcurl.so.3 in local folder and set LD_LIBRARY_PATH according. When I link my entire project it says that there is version conflict between libcurl.so.4 and libcurl.so.3 required libprivate.so (libprivate.so is compiled long time ago with libcurl.3.so).

Should I not worry about this warning and proceed further?

When I correctly specify LD_LIBRARY_PATH which has libcurl.so.3, why it is taking from system directory /usr/lib64/libcurl.so.4? when I do ldd my_binary, it takes from libcurl.so.4. How do I stop it? Specifying -L with specific location also doesn't work. Modiying /etc/ld.conf will do for the entire system. I want to make this when I ran my project.

Specifying explicit path it works like /home/mydir/libcurl.so.3, but I do not want to do it.

I want to have these conditions only when I execute my project. In other cases it can make use of latest libraries.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Could the dependency on `libcurl.so.4` be coming from another library? You can use [`tldd`](https://gitorious.org/tldd/tldd/source/HEAD:tldd.cc) to see where a library dependency comes from. If it's not from another library, please show your entire linker command.

Comment: I had simple testing. Here is the command for compiling and linking gcc test.c -L~/lib/x86_64/ -lcurl -o test. I had also set LD_LIBRARY_PATH to ~/lib/x86_64. But when I do ldd test, it says that /usr/lib64/libcurl.so.4

Comment: I expect to pick libcurl.so.3 from ~/lib/x86_64. but ldd shows that it picks from system library libcurl.so.4 in /usr/lib64.

Comment: You need a space between `-L` and `~/lib/x86_64/` or the shell won't expand the `~`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the command you show in your comment is correct:

```
gcc test.c -L~/lib/x86_64/ -lcurl -o test
```

... then you need a space between `-L` and `~/lib/x86_64/` or the shell won't expand the `~`, so the linker is not looking in the right directory.

So you need either:

```
gcc test.c -L ~/lib/x86_64/ -lcurl -o test
```

or:

```
gcc test.c -L$HOME/lib/x86_64/ -lcurl -o test
```

(You don't need a space here because variables are expanded anywhere in a word, but `~` is only expanded at the start of a word.)

Comment: It seems like it works now. But I am getting undefined reference to `FIPS_mode' error now. I never use such function in my source. It is only empty source code in main.

Comment: You might need to add `-lssl` or `-lcrypto` or something like that

Comment: No it does not help, it seems like there is some problem in using old ssl library in new environment?

Comment: It seems to be libssl issue, let me post another question with ssl title. But taking old library issue is solved. Thanks so much for help.

Comment: Solved this problem. I did not have right version libcrypto in my local folder. I copied the right version. It solved.